# How can I create computed column on EF 6.0 Migration if there isn't HasComputedColumnSql

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I need to add a computed column for location data, as I have a separate column for latitude and longitude, but need a `DbGeography` property to calculate the distance.

EF Core has a method `HasComputedColumnSql`, but I couldn't find an equivalent for EF 6.0. What option do I have to create the computed column from my migrations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First mark you column as computed:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
public double Distance { get; private set; }
```

In your migration, you can simply run some custom SQL:

```
Sql("ALTER TABLE Blah ADD Distance AS (...)");
```

Where `...` is the SQL you need to have in your computed column.